# NullPointerException when trying to use ImageViewer

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-imageview

So i'm trying to make a rock paper scissors game, it worked fine until I wanted to add fragments. I had to change alot of things up and now I can't get this thing to work. It's hard to explain so I will just show you the code where it's important. I'm VERY new to programming overall.

Fragmenttwo

```
private static Fragment theFragment;

private void clickListener(choice mychoice){
    hideButtons();

    choice compchoice = choice.choices.getRandom();
    //int outcome = choice.decideOutcome(mychoice, compchoice);

    compchoice.getImage(theFragment, compchoice);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
     final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_board, container, false);

                Button rbutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonRock); 

                rbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rockdone);

                    choice mychoice = new choice(choices.ROCK);

                    clickListener(mychoice);
                }              
            }); 
     return view;
 }
```

choices class

```
private static ActionBarActivity theActivity;

public static enum choices {
    ROCK,
    SCISSOR,
    PAPER,

    public static choice getRandom() {
        return new choice(values()[(int) (Math.random() * values().length)]);
    }
}

public View getImage(Fragment a, choice compchoice){
    ImageView image = (ImageView) theActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageViewer);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rockcom);
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  return null;
}
```

start_board.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/start_board"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/rps9"
android:visibility="visible" >

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonRock"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:text="@string/brock"
    android:textColorLink="@android:color/transparent"
    android:visibility="visible" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/rockcom"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat

```
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066): Process: com.gerfort.gerfortrps, PID: 2066
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at com.gerfort.gerfortrps.choice.getImage(choice.java:39)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at com.gerfort.gerfortrps.Fragmenttwo.clickListener(Fragmenttwo.java:108)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at com.gerfort.gerfortrps.Fragmenttwo.access$2(Fragmenttwo.java:101)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at com.gerfort.gerfortrps.Fragmenttwo$4.onClick(Fragmenttwo.java:165)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at     android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-14 08:57:20.964: E/AndroidRuntime(2066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Please inform me if I forgot any code.

Comment: I would also like to know why this post got a dislike so I can perhaps ask a question in a better way the next time. Hate to not know the reasoning behind why it was a bad question.

Comment: You cant do : ImageView image = (ImageView) theActivity.findViewById(R.id.imageViewer);

Comment: How shall I do it then?

Comment: Is it in the Fragment?

Comment: The ImageView? No, i'm not using it inside my Fragmenttwo.

Comment: try with `a.getView().findViewById(R.id.imageViewer);`

Comment: Why are you returning NULL in `getImage`?? it's firing NPE. return View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `ImageView` instead of fragment to the method *getImage*

Change this :

`compchoice.getImage(theFragment, compchoice);`

To :

```
compchoice.getImage(image, compchoice);
```

and initialize ImageView in `onCreateView` as :

```
image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewer);
```

New method signature will be :

```
public void getImage(ImageView image, choice compchoice)
```

And code will be :

```
public void getImage(ImageView image, choice compchoice){

    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rockcom);
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Fragment.getView()' on a null object reference
at com.gerfort.gerfortrps.choice.getImage(choice.java:39)"

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply add imageview as,

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewer);
```

thats it..

Comment: Where? Cannot be resoloved in the choice class

Comment: because you inflates start_board but not create object of imageview... so it gives you exception..